# var_dump() is giving me NULL AND bool(false)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im working on a php lottery script, but i seem to be having some issues?
when i do 
var_dump($choose) returns "bool(false)"
and
var_dump($choose['username']) returns "NULL"

Any one got any ideas? 
This is "$choose":

```
$choose = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `lotto` WHERE winner = '1'");
```

my table name is lotto, username and winner both exist as columns in "lotto"

this is the full snippet of the code:

```html
$choose = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `lotto` WHERE winner = '1'");
$chosen = mysql_fetch_assoc($choose);
 
  if ($choose >= $choose)
   {
   
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO lotto_winners (username, time, winning_number) VALUES ('".$choose['username']."', '1', '".$winner."')");
}
else 
{
 echo 'FAILED: No Winner to Choose From';
}
  


echo
'<div>'.$winner.'</div>';
echo
'<div>'.$choose.'</div>';

 
var_dump($chosen);
var_dump($chosen['username']);
```

and BEFORE anyone says anything: I already know that mysql_* is deprecated. so please, you dont need to tell me.

Comment: You do realise that `if ($choose >= $choose)` will always be true?

Answer (score 0):

from  PHP Doc

> **Converting to boolean**
>
> To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean)
>   casts. However, in most cases the cast is unnecessary, since a value
>   will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control
>   structure requires a boolean argument.
>
> See also Type Juggling.
>
> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- **an array with zero elements**  (*Your Case*)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

then the $choose is null because no rows are return 
if the winner column data type is number   try using

```
 $choose "SELECT username FROM `lotto` WHERE winner = 1"
```

or if you are using an enum then try filter for the values associated to 1

```
   $choose "SELECT username FROM `lotto` WHERE winner = 'MY_VALUE_FOR_1'"
```

Comment: so if thats the case, how would this work?



$getRewards = mysql_query("SELECT credits FROM users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'");
           while ($rewards = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRewards)){
                                       
                          
                                            if ($rewards['credits'] > 19999)
           

and that works 100% fine, i dont really see the difference?

Comment: Your question is about $choose. $choose  is null  this is the reason for your  var_dump result .. and my answer is about you quest . if $choose is null .. this mean  that you query   don't work but this is another question  .. could be you have an error somewhere ..  do the fact this is the case you comment is not related  to the your original question

Comment: my comment, was because i set $rewards up, just like i did with the $choose. i dont understand why it isnt working the same..

Comment: i have update the answer  with a suggestion  .. (could be you have a number data type and not a char)

Comment: okay, i got you with that part. i have winner as  enum('0', '1') thats why i put the single quotes around '1' and when i run the query into my database itself, it works just fine, pulls up the one single winner in the table, and lists the username

http://prntscr.com/gf1fbn

Comment: this comment  what mean  ?  that my answer  and suggestion are right or not?

Comment: No, Still NULL is what im saying.

Comment: Firts my answer  is right because answer  at your question  ..  you question is not why my select don't work  ..  but why var_dump return  this value  so  you should accept my answer  and post a new question for find the reason you query don'y work  ..  SO is not coding service or a tutorila service  ,,is a question answer  site ..   just a last tip  ... your enum   which values have  ???? related  to 1

Answer (score -1):

Your query is invalid, thats why you get bool(false)

change

```
"SELECT username FROM `lotto` WHERE winner = '1'"
```

to

```
"SELECT username FROM lotto WHERE winner = '1'"
```

Comment: the back ticks were only an attempt for a fix. it doesnt work with them gone either.